# selecting the first parent

Tags: jquery

js

```
$(".deletable").live('click',function(){
      $(this).parent().effect('explode', 500, function(){
            $(this).parent().remove();
      })
});
```

html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='deletable'>hi</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<ul>
    <li>
        <span class=deletable>hi</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to remove the `tr` in case `td` is clicked and the `li` case `span` is clicked.

For some reason this is not working and instead the whole `ul`/`table` is deleted.

Why so ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For some reason this is not working and instead the whole ul/table is
>   deleted.
>
> Why so ?

In your current code `this` within the click event refers to the clicked element.
You then traverse to the element's parent to call `effect` on it `$(this).parent().effect...`.

Within the effect call `this` is now referring to the parent (`li/tr`) but you call `$(this).parent().remove();` traversing to the parent of the parent (`ul/table`), hence removing the whole `list/table`.

Change your code to only use `$(this).remove();` inside your effect call instead as it already refers to the desired parent element (`li/tr`), like this:

```
$(".deletable").live('click',function(){
      $(this).parent().effect('explode', 500, function(){
            $(this).remove();
      })
});
```

Comment: @MomenMElZalabany: You are welcome. What `this` refers to can be confusing at times within nested calls. In most cases when using jQuery it refers to the object you are calling the method on.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
$(".deletable").live('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().effect('explode', 500, function(){
        // $(this) is still your parent
        $(this).remove();
    })
});
```

Comment: yep, this one. how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use selector for .parent as well. http://api.jquery.com/parent/

```
$(this).parent("tr").remove();
```

How do you understand that the whole table/ul is removed if you are looking it debug tool and the table/ul only have 1 child element the browser can delete the table/ul as well, as with out children they are meaningless.

Can you try this when the table/ul have multiple children?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$(this).parents("li:first").remove();
```